# python find section in file with most regular expression match occurences

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I'm reading a file line per line and checking where a code section ends: a specific sequence of characters appears. This sequence could occur within the code section so i have to check the redundancy : how many times successive lines contains the sequence. with 10 successive occurences i should return the first line where the successive occurences started to detect the end of the code section.

```
regexp_dict_02 = {'Name': 'EMPTY_PAGES', 'Expr':  '(FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)'}
def FindEmptyPg(Inpfile,Section):

 NbrLine = []
 Pos = []
 flag = 0
 index = 0
 Ln = 0

 with open(Inpfile) as fp:
  for i, line in enumerate(fp):
   if i >= Section.startline and i < 30061 :
    s=re.search(regexp_dict_02['Expr'],line)
    if s:  
     NbrLine.append(i)


  logging.info (NbrLine)
  logging.info (len(NbrLine)) 
  for index in range((len(NbrLine))-1):
   if NbrLine[index+1] - NbrLine[index] == 1 : 
    logging.info (str (NbrLine[index+1]) + '  ' + str(NbrLine[index]))
    Pos.append (index)
    flag += 1   
    if flag == 5 : 
     Ln = NbrLine[Pos[0]]
     break
  logging.info (Pos)
  return Ln
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGaEK.png)

in the above Code I'm checking only on two successive lines and i get the wrong line number. i avoided using complicated stuff like state machines and so on  but im still stuck.

Comment: I am not sure I got your question. Do you want to output the index of the first line of a block of at least 10 lines, ALL containing your pattern of interest?

Comment: i want to output the line number  where the block with the maximum regex match occurences starts.Minimum 10 occurences. This block will indicate the empty data.

Comment: Must the occurrences be consecutives, non interrupted?

Comment: exactly! you can take a look at the image . i tried to highlight the concerned  part of the file as example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution. The following code iterates over each line. Every time a match is found, it adds the line index into `block`. As soon a line without any matches is found, the block is considered "closed" and a new empty block is created, but before that, it saves the len of the block and the first index in `results`. Those are the only info you are interested in. Last, you sort `results` and pick the last item (sort of list of tuples will sort by default by the first item of the tuple, in this case the len of the block), a tuple containing the longest block found with the index of the first line for that block.

```
t = \
'''
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
00001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00011111
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
000010000000000000000000000000000000000011111
'''

pattern = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
block = []
results = []
for i, line in enumerate(t.split('\n')):
    if pattern in line:
        block.append(i)
    else:
        try:
            results.append((len(block), block[0])) #save the len and the first index of each block
            block = []
        except IndexError:
            pass


cons, index = sorted(results)[-1] #number of consecutive match, line index
print(f'max consecutive matches found: {cons} , stating at line {index}')
```

Output:

```
max consecutive matches found: 14 , stating at line 11
```

To address the comment:

> I need the first sufficient successive occurrences: first 10
>   successive occurrences matched then I catch the line.

You can use the following code instead.

```
pattern = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
block = []
for i, line in enumerate(t.split('\n')):
    if pattern in line:
        block.append(i)
    else:
        if len(block) >= 10:
            print(f'found a block of at least 10 lines starting from line {block[0]}')
            break
        block = []
```

Comment: well i dont need where the max consecutive matches are found because i have other code section in the file. I need the first sufficient successive occurences : first 10 successive occurences matched then i catch the line .

Comment: All the data is in results. Just check for the tuples having 10 or more as the first item and you got it.

Comment: with the 'string in Line' Check i wasn't able to catch all the occurences. replacing it with the Regex yielded to the desired result. @alec_djinn: any explication ? Thanks for all .

Comment: @MomoEssassi Hard to tell why it is not working with `if string in line`, your regex does basically the same thing. I would need the source file to figure it out.